# How to turn $-\ln(1-x^2)$ into a power series representation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I need to turn $f(x)=-\ln(1-x^2)$ into a power series, there are 2 things I can't understand:

1) I don't how to check and even if to check whether this function can turn into a power series or not, because the Lecturer gave us the following statement: $\text{Let f(x) be a diffrentiable function}\infty\text{ times in (-R,R) then we can turn f(x) into a power series }<=>\text{ Lagrange form of the remainder $R_n(x) $ statisfies that } \lim_{n\to \infty}R_n(x) = 0$ And I am not sure how to use it.

2) If I assume that it can turn into a power series, I know that $ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}}$, and I really don't know what can I do with it. In your answer, if you could please add few tips how to solve these kinds of questions, it will be great. I also don't know if i am allowed to say that $$\ln (t)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n+1}\frac{t^n}{n}}$$
and then $t=1-x^2$? Can I do that?

Comment: Can you define $R_n(x)$ for the given $f$? Edit: thank you for clarifying.

Comment: It's not homework, I am learning for a test.

Comment: W.r.t. you last addition, why would that be justified? You've substituted $t$ for both $x$ and $1+x$ (and $x\ne 1+x$).

Comment: I see no reason why not (as long as you pay attention to $R$, the radius of convergence).

Comment: Try using that $-\ln(1-x^2)=-\ln(1+ (-x^2))$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

You started well using $$ln(1+x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}}$$ Now change $x$ to $-x$ to get $$ln(1-x)=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{x^n}{n}}$$ Now replace $x$ by $t^2$ and finish.

I am sure you can take from here.

Comment: Can you please explain when should I check that Lagrange form of the remainder converges to 0?

Comment: For the series you consider, how does write Lagrange form of the remainder ?  Remember that $|x|<1$

Answer (score 0):

for $g(x)=\ln(1-x)$ for $x \in (-1,1)$ you have

$g(0)=0$

$g'(x)=\frac{-1}{1-x}$ $g'(0)=-1$

$g''(x)=\frac{-1}{(1-x)^2}$ $g''(0)=-1$

...........

$g^{(n)}(x)=\frac{-(n-1)!}{(1-x)^n}$, $g^{(n)}(0)=-(n-1)!$

.......

Then the Taylor series for $g(x)$ is

$\ln(1-x)=0-\frac{0!}{1!}x-\frac{1!}{2!}x^2-\ldots-\frac{(n-1)!}{n!}x^n\ldots$

That is

$\ln(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}{2}-\ldots-\frac{x^n}{n}\ldots$

for $x\in (-1,1)$

Now for $x \in (-1,1)$ $x^2\in [0,1)$ and you have to replace $x$ by $x^2$ to get

$\ln(1-x^2)=-x^2-\frac{x^4}{2}-\ldots-\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\ldots$

Comment: You have a few typo's. The $!$ must disappear in the last two formulas.

Comment: Yes, sir!. I correct it.